# Bottom Navigation with Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-transitions, bottomnavigationview

I have an application where it is required to persist the bottom navigation across multiple screen. Now naturally bottom navigation works well with fragments but the problem is that my other fragments also have other screens to call which is usually delegated back to the handling activity.

With said, when i tried implementing the bottom navigation with fragments the activity becomes a God Activity where it handles all fragments.

So my solution was to start an activity instead. But the problem with this approach is that every start of the activity the activity transition makes it obvious an activity is being started. I tried setting off the activity transition to avoid this but now Im left with a very static page which just suddenly changes. I still want my views to animate smoothly between screen changes.

Can someone give me an advice here. Heres what I would want to achieve in summary:
1) make it seem the bottom navigation was not changed/moved (and hopefull still have the shifting animation if possible)
2) animate smoothly between screen changes
3) also still have the capability of having shared element transition if possible.

Please help me here. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: can u tried for this ?

Comment: I dont quite understand

Comment: Smooth animation can be easily achieved even when starting an Activity through intent. I think using Shared element transition would fit.